# Eigenvalues—I’m getting wrong result

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

On pp. 280–281 of the book *Solar System Dynamics* (https://books.google.ca/books?id=aU6vcy5L8GAC&printsec=frontcover#v=twopage&q&f=true), eigenvalues $ g $ and eigenvectors $ \bar e_{ji} $ of matrix $ \mathbf A = \begin{pmatrix} +0.00203738 & -0.00132987 \\ -0.00328007 & +0.00502513 \end{pmatrix} $ (p. 280) are calculated. The results are $ g_1 = 9.63435 \times 10^{-4} $ and $ g_2 = 6.09908 \times 10^{-3} $ (p. 280, which I also get) and $ \bar e = \begin{pmatrix} -0.777991 & 0.332842 \\ -0.628275 & -1.01657 \end{pmatrix} $ (p. 281), or at least the way I understand the problem (I haven’t done matrices in 30+ years, and *never* did eigenvalues or eigenvectors before now).

I get wholly different results for $ \bar e $, though… $ \begin{pmatrix} -0.35001 & 1.15833 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $, for example, with https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-eigenvectors-calculator. These are not even scalable to the values given in the book, so it’s not a matter of multiplying them by a constant…

What am I doing wrong? or misunderstanding?

Thanks in advance for any help!

P.S. There are published errata for this book, e.g. the value of $ S_2\ \text{sin}\ \beta_2 $ at the bottom of p. 281 should be $ -0.0375549 $ instead of $ -0.375549 $, but never any mention of any error in $ \bar e $…

Answer (score 1):

Maple says $$\overline{e}=\begin{pmatrix}                                   
             -0.777991219286310 &    0.311162928367653 \\
             -0.628275148890516 &   -0.950356581504893
\end{pmatrix}$$
This is not so far from the book's answer you quote. Another possibility is (after scaling)
$$\overline{e}=\begin{pmatrix}                                   
             1,2383 &    -0.3274 \\
             1 &   1
\end{pmatrix}$$
which is close to what you found, if you transpose the matrix (representing vectors in columns and not in line, perhaps..).

Comment: OK, but how do I calculate it? I don’t want to use “ready-made” solutions like apps or websites. I want to be able to calculate it on a piece of paper.

Comment: @PierrePaquette once you found an eigenvalue, say, $\lambda_1$, you solve $(a_{11}- \lambda_1) x =- a_{12} $ and your eigenvector is $\begin{pmatrix}x\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @PierrePaquette formula 7.42 on page 281 is revealing. The vector with both entries $1/\sqrt 2$ is entirely correct.  The vector above it is also a vector of length 1, and is correct. However, nonsense in both other vectors

Comment: Thanks! It seems like I had not transcribed those formulas properly from my source to my notes!

Comment: @PierrePaquette well, there is a real problem with 7.42; that is not your fault. Unless you wrote the book. I psted the pages into an answer window

Comment: @username: But calculating it by hand with your formula gives me $e_{11} = 1.238304$, not $-0.77799121986310$, so how do Maple and the book get that result? (The values in formulas 7.47 depend on these precise values.)

Comment: @PierrePaquette   the $e_{11}$  and $e_{21}$ values are normalised to unit length, in that the sum of their squares is $1.$

Comment: @WillJagy: What about $e_{12}$ and $e_{22}$? How does the book get those values?

Comment: @PierrePaquette They talk about that between 7.42 and 7.47. The values for the T and S factors are 7.49. Evidently these come from specific trigonometric values as in 7.48.  This suggests that there is something very important about the particular choices of eigenvector multiples.  One would need several pages of the book to work out what they really want.

Comment: @WillJagy: Most of the necessary parts are available at the link I gave above (https://books.google.ca/books?id=aU6vcy5L8GAC&printsec=frontcover#v=twopage&q&f=true)

Comment: @PierrePaquette from what I am seeing, you ought to get some one on one help. I remember a medical doctor in Denver with some statistics trouble. It turned out that the University statistics department did provide consulting, modest price for graduate student, big money for professor. I do think there is a Astronomy site https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/  Try that if you have not already.

Comment: Plus it does say that the eigenvectors in 7.42 are UNscaled! So no, the discussion between 7.42 and 7.48 is for scaled values of e in 7.50 (page 282).

Comment: @WillJagy: Astronomy Stack Exchange voted to close my question because it belongs here, in their opinion. Believe me, I asked it there, too…

Comment: it let me see pages 278, 279, along with 280, 281. They have reached ODE systems by 7.27, so that explains the interest in eigenvectors. I see, actually two four by four systems, block skew symmetric, so pure imaginary. That explains 7.28 and 7.29.

Comment: @WillJagy: Ouch… Basically everything you said in your last comment sounds like gibberish to me… Like I said, matrices are very far in my academic past (heck, my academic past is very far!), and I never even heard of eigenwhatevers before a few months ago at most.

Comment: @PierrePaquette if you can scan in the pages I can't see, from the beginning of chapter 7  to 282 and a few pages more, email me those, I can make a better guess as to what is needed. My email is visible at  https://mathoverflow.net/users/3324/will-jagy?tab=profile

Comment: Thanks! I’ll do that later. Please remember; I’m a newbie to all this, so high-school explanations, please! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From the book___________________________________

On the right hand page, formulas (7.42) show problems.

$$  $$

[image]